# start sshd with /usr/sbin/sshd in centos

Tags: ssh, centos6, service

I am new in linux but newest in Centos.

using
**CentOS release 6.6 (Final)**

I can start ssh service via `service sshd start` and get this output

```
Generating SSH2 RSA host key:                              [  OK  ]
Generating SSH1 RSA host key:                              [  OK  ]
Generating SSH2 DSA host key:                              [  OK  ]
Starting sshd:                                             [  OK  ]
```

And can after connect via ssh without problem.

But I need start ssh via `/usr/sbin/sshd -D` and get this output

```
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
```

and the service do not start.

Comment: Why do you not want to start sshd normally?

Comment: `/usr/sbin/sshd` is not what generates that output.

Comment: @michael-hampton I need to start like deamon in one docker CMD like this, **CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]** which works in ubuntu.

Comment: Well that is important information that should have been in your question.  Have you created ssh host keys within your container?  Your error messages strongly indicates that you haven't.

Comment: FYI - running an sshd inside your docker containers is almost certainly not the right thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output in your first example is actually from the init script. Check `/etc/init.d/sshd` if you want to see the full context of what is happening there.

If you're trying to replicate this in a docker container, you will need to replicate. The important commands are:

```
$KEYGEN -q -t rsa -f $RSA_KEY -C '' -N ''
$KEYGEN -q -t dsa -f $DSA_KEY -C '' -N ''
```

Which once you expand all the variables, becomes:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -C '' -N ''
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -q -t dsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key -C '' -N ''
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are trying to start the sshd application with a non-root user.

The permissions of the host key file only allow root to read them.

```
4 -rw-r--r--.   1 root root   2047 Nov  6 09:07 ssh_config
4 -rw-------.   1 root root   3879 Nov  6 09:07 sshd_config
4 -rw-------.   1 root root    672 Jun 23 13:32 ssh_host_dsa_key
4 -rw-------.   1 root root    963 Jun 23 13:32 ssh_host_key
4 -rw-------.   1 root root   1675 Jun 23 13:32 ssh_host_rsa_key
```

In CentOS6, selinux can block some actions so you may need to have a look in:

```
/var/log/audit/audit.log
```

I hope this helps.